# How do I display WooCommerce products in my query to rows of 3?

Tags: php, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, loop

I have created a WooCommerce search plugin. It fetches products, however it only displays the products as one per row.

How can I amend my query to display 3 products per row? Here is the function:

```
 function realtime_product_search_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('realtime-product-search', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'realtime-product-search.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('realtime-product-search', 'realtime_product_search_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'realtime_product_search_enqueue_scripts');

function perform_product_search() {
    $searchQuery = isset($_POST['search_query']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['search_query']) : '';
    $categoryFilter = isset($_POST['category_filter']) ? $_POST['category_filter'] : array();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        's' => $searchQuery,
    );

    if (!empty($categoryFilter)) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $categoryFilter,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        );
    }

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    $count = 0;

    if ($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div class="product-row">'; // Start the product row
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            if ($count % 3 === 0 && $count > 0) {
                echo '</div><div class="product-row">'; // Close previous row and start a new row after every 3 products
            }
            wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
            $count++;
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>'; // Close the last product row
    } else {
        echo __('No products found');
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not determine how many show per row; you'd use CSS to accomplish that.